# Snowflake: clustering on datetime key stored in variant field does not work / do partition pruning

Tags: database-performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, clustering-key

We are ingesting data into Snowflake via the [kafka connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector.html).
To increase the data read performance / scan less partitions we decided to add a [clustering key](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html) to a a key / combination of keys stored in the RECORD_CONTENT variant field.

The data in the RECORD_CONTENT field looks like this:

```
{
  "jsonSrc": {
    "Integerfield": 1,
    "SourceDateTime": "2020-06-30 05:33:08:345",
    *REST_OF_THE_KEY_VALUE_PAIRS*
}
```

Now, the issue is that clustering on a datetime col like **SourceDateTime** does **NOT** work:

```
CLUSTER BY (to_date(RECORD_CONTENT:jsonSrc:loadDts::datetime))
```

...while clustering on a field like **Integerfield** **DOES** work:

```
CLUSTER BY (RECORD_CONTENT:jsonSrc:Integerfield::int )
```

**Not working means**: when using a filter on **RECORD_CONTENT:jsonSrc:loadDts::datetime**, it has **no effect** on the partitions scanned, while filtering on **RECORD_CONTENT:jsonSrc:Integerfield::int** does perform partition pruning.

*What is wrong here? Is this a bug?*

**Note that:**

- There is **enough** data to do meaningful clustering on **RECORD_CONTENT:jsonSrc:loadDts::datetime**
- I validated clustering on RECORD_CONTENT:jsonSrc:loadDts::datetime working by making a copy of the raw table, with RECORD_CONTENT:jsonSrc:loadDts::datetime in a **seperate column**  **loadDtsCol** and then adding a similar clustering key on that column: to_date(loadDtsCol).

Comment: Did you try filter on  RECORD_CONTENT:jsonSrc:loadDts without casting to datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For better pruning and less storage consumption, we recommend
> flattening your object and key data into separate relational columns
> if your semi-structured data includes:  Dates and timestamps,
> especially non-ISO 8601dates and timestamps, as string values
>
> Numbers within strings
>
> Arrays
>
> Non-native values such as dates and timestamps are stored as strings
> when loaded into a VARIANT column, so operations on these values could
> be slower and also consume more space than when stored in a relational
> column with the corresponding data type.

See this link:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-considerations.html#storing-semi-structured-data-in-a-variant-column-vs-flattening-the-nested-structure

Comment: Thanks mike. I guess I need to read this as 'for ANY pruning at all to work, when the data contains timestamps, it needs to be stored in a separate column' .
Because whatever I tried with the datetime field, partition pruning does not work at all...